# Every sequence of probability measures on a compact metric space is tight

Tags: probability-theory

Let S be a compact metric space and let (μn) be a sequence of probability measures
on S. Prove that (μn) possesses a weakly convergent subsequence.

I am trying to prove that (μn) is tight;which will imply the rest because of Prokhorov's theorem.

Can somebody help me on this...Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: See also the Riesz-Markov(-Kakutani?) theorem, apply Banach-Alaoglu and show that in the dual of a separable Banach, the weak-star topology on the unit ball is metrizable.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use MathJax to typeset your posts. Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3):

Note that since $S$ itself is compact $\mu_n(S)=1$ for all $n$, hence there exists a single compact set $K=S$ so that $\mu_n(K) \ge 1- \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$.